# Running Java/Scala code from R

Tags: java, r, scala, h2o

I want to run a some Java or Scala code from within R (to be more specific, I'd like to run the POJO built by H2O from within R itself). Is there a way to do that? So far I just found solutions for the opposite case, of executing R programs from Java..

Comment: `system()` for running java as program passing your code file name as argument?

Comment: Possible after compiling the Java code to a jar. I was wondering if there's a way of using the actual class itself..

Comment: @shakedzy As you marked an answer correct, does that mean you successfully ran the h2o.jar + pojo from within R? If so, I'd love to hear more. (Was it easy? Was there a measurable speed-up compared to just running the H2O server?)

Comment: If you are just trying to load an H2O model from an R session, you may prefer to use a binary H2O model (see `h2o.saveModel` and `h2o.loadModel`) instead of the POJO H2O model.

Comment: @DarrenCook, no I haven't tried it yet with the POJO, just followed the tutorial and saw I can use Java within R. Now, given Erin's comment, I might actually try that first..

Comment: @ErinL. thanks for your comment, it sounds like something worth trying!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try [rJava](http://www.rforge.net/rJava/). This will allow you to call Java class from your R program in a more native fashion. A basic `HelloWorld` tutorial is [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/R/entry/using_rjava_in_embedded_r)